# Run scenario with customized tags in behave framework

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

how to make a selection of scenarios to run using customized tags?

For Eaxmple,the following is feature file

```
Feature:my example feature 

@Test_Name:sample @abc:1234 @sd:567

Scenario: Example scenario
 Given my Name is sample
 When my Name is whensample
 Then  my Name is endsample
```

I have multiple feature files and each feature file has many scenarios.scenario tags are similar the way mentioned above.
I am trying to get run the scenario

```
   behave -t Test_Name --> to run all files
   behave -t abcd --> run specific scenario
   behave -t 1234 --> run specific scenario
```

Please suggest if is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

add tags to scenarios like @testtag1, @testtag2 as shown below

```
Feature: showing off behave
  @testtag1
  Scenario: run a simple test
     Given we have behave installed
      when we implement a test
      then behave will test it for us!

  @testtag2
  Scenario: run a simple test2
     Given we have behave installed
      when we implement a test
      then behave will test it for us!

@testtag1
  Scenario: run a simple test3
     Given we have behave installed
      when we implement a test
      then behave will test it for us!
```

Run the command

```
behave --tags=testtag1
```

to test scenarios whose tag is testtag1

Answer (score 0):

## Created by Surbhi at 09-07-2020

Feature: # Enter feature name here

@chrome
Scenario:

Given user Test selenium on python with chrome

@ff

Scenario:

Given user Test selenium on python with firefox

UseCommand : 
behave -t=chrome  and behave -t=ff in param configuration

or you can also use : behave --tags=@chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnEC.png)